# Spammer signs up again with the same auto-increment ID

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a small website where the user can sign up via a HTML form. 
The data is than stored via PHP in a MySQL database.
I often delete spammers from the records manually. Normally, when I fx delete the entry 222,
the next user/bot who signs up gets the ID 223 as ID is auto-increment. But the last couple of days 
one bot always signed up again and got the same ID, even though it should have been higher than before.
Any idea how they succeed with this? And how to stop this?
Thanks!

Edit: here is (part of) my code

```
if ($_POST['process'] == 1) {
$varMail = $_POST['email'];
$varMail = strtolower($varMail);
$varCountry = $_POST['country'];
$varPwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$varConf = $_POST['pwdconf'];

if (isset($_POST['newsletter'])) {
  $newsletter = 1;
}

if ($varMail != '' && $varCountry != '' && $varPwd != '' && $varConf != '' && $varPwd == $varConf) {
try{
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=:username AND status=1");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $varMail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($row_count == 0) {
$varRandom = md5(rand());
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$pwd = SHA1($varPwd);
try{
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user(username, pwd, country, newsletter, status, random, registered) VALUES(:username, :pwd, :country, :newsletter, '0', :random, :date)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $varMail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':country', $varCountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':newsletter', $newsletter, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':random', $varRandom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That would very much depend on the code on your site.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: Spam from bots ? Maybe a captcha can filter some of them.

Comment: Would also say a Code Problem. An easy additional Security measure is to add a hidden Value that when filled will let the registration go trough but invalidates the User as Bot. Most Bots fill every Form Field in a HTML Form, you may sort a bunch of them out like that.

Comment: If your spammer always get the same ID, you are actually lucky : It makes it easier to detect and delete its spams ! Anyway, instead of fixing this autoincrement problem, you'd better fix the spam issue

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Of course I need to implement something to stop them from signing up but as this problem is very small at the moment I can easily fix it by deleting manually. The bots never activate the account anyways. But I am more concerned about and want to understand why the bot always has the same auto-increment ID!

Comment: Is ID a primary key by the way ?

Comment: @JackyCheng The table was only created once - manually in phpMyAdmin. It is also in phpMyAdmin that I delete the entry by clicking on "delete" in the row of the entry.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `newsletter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `random` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `registered` date NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `read_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=389 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

Comment: i got nothing, the 3 things i can think of is that you either have a insert sql somewhere else that's subject to SQL injextion, you did a rollback somewhere after the delete or you didn't actually commit your delete so it shows back up everytime you check.

Comment: @JackyCheng Thanks for your effort! Will monitor it further!

Comment: Doesn't help with your problem, but you seem to try and find an existing user of status 1 with the new username. If non found then you try and do an insert. But username is unique so if you potentially are trying to insert multiple status 0 users with the same username (all but the first should fail).

Comment: @Kickstart Thanks, seems like you are right. My check is from a time before I changed username to unique. Wanted to check if the user already is signed up.

Comment: I can't see anything in this code that would allow them to insert another record with the same auto incremented id. Have you changed the current auto increment number? Is there possibly some other code that does an insert. Is there some code somewhere that possibly has an sql injection hole?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how they succeed with this?

As @sevenseacat said, it depends on your code.

> And how to stop this?

Captcha

Comment: i don't think that's the core issue. The issue is why the bot always get the entry id 222.